# How to get reference of parent view with respect window

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my extJS app I have one button. Onclick of that button I created a window. I want to access view of parent app. How to get that.

What I am trying here is  in windowController

```
init: function() {
        var me = this
        var me = this.view
    },
```

But here I am getting view of window. I want view of base. Any lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can pass the parent view while creating window component

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        xtype: 'window',
        parentView: view,
        ......
})
```

it would be more helpful if you share your code.